# Error to loading the file from the package in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS2015 for developing the angular application. For cheking authentication token is expired or not I added one package using cmd command window using below code

`npm install --save @auth0/angular-jwt` 
In the authentication.service class as below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService{
constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {}

public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
 }
}
```

There is no compile error, But in browser it shows below error while running

> Error loading http://localhost:XXX/@auth0/angular-jwt as "@auth0/angular-jwt" from http://localhost:XXX/app/_services/authentication.service.js.

Also I added the below code in the systemjs.config.js file in the map section.

```
'angular-jwt': 'npm:@auth0/angular-jwt'
```

But still it showing the same. If I missing something? Package is present in the path

> node_modules\@auth0\angular-jwt

Answer (score 0):

You have to add whitelistedDomains, in your `app.module.ts` add following

```
@NgModule({
imports:
    [
        ..., // Your other modules
        JwtModule.forRoot({
            config: {
              tokenGetter: () => {
                return localStorage.getItem('token');
              },
              whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:4200']
            }      
        }),
        ... // Your other modules
    ],
....
```

Comment: Error loading http://localhost:XXX/@auth0/angular-jwt as "@auth0/angular-jwt" from http://localhost:XXX/app/app.module.js

Comment: can you create a plunker/stackblitz of your code so that I can have a better idea?